# Capturing all groups after a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have something similar to this:

```
A: 1 2 3 4
B: 5 6 7 8
C: 9 10 11 12
```

I am interested in capturing the numbers in the `B` row. In other words, I want to match `[' 5',' 6',' 7',' 8']`. Bear in mind that I am not guaranteed that the number of rows or the amount of digits is like in my example.

The closest I got to is `(?<=B:)( \d+)*`, which matches:

[image]

What is the correct way of doing what I want **strictly** in Python regular expressions? Is it possible?

Edit: Some people rightly mentioned I could simply capture the row and then use split inside Python. This surely works, but the problem is that I am limited to using only a single regular expression.

Comment: have you consider just using split?

Comment: @ChristianSloper Certainly. The issue is that I can only use a single expression which I pass to a program through a file, so I can't really have anything fancier I'm afraid.

Comment: Since what you ask for is impossible, please consider modifying your workflow.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was afraid it wouldn't be possible, but I had to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) that supports a quantifier in the lookbehind assertion:

```
(?<=B:[ \d]*)\d+
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is to the left is

  - `B:[ \d]*` Match `B:` and optional spaces or digits
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gXX2kn/1/) or a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##RY1BCsIwFAX3OcXjrxItYlq1GixiPYZxUUjUQE1DmoWePlYRnOUbeBNe6T74Kmf3CENMiPZmn4yFLiUbPRpE4od906oztLnMhDZzYmycBKejgkSJCivtieEDtQprbFBj@99OCjvIJaSELElM79H5xL@pxdV50/U9/xULjELk/AY).

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?<=B:[ \d]*)\d+"

s = ("A: 1 2 3 4\n"
     "B: 5 6 7 8\n"
     "C: 9 10 11 12")

print(regex.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['5', '6', '7', '8']
```

---

If you can not use the regex module, you can use a capture group and split:

```
import re

pattern = r"B: (\d+(?: \d+)*)"

s = ("A: 1 2 3 4\n"
     "B: 5 6 7 8\n"
     "C: 9 10 11 12")

res = re.search(pattern, s)
if res:
     print(res.group(1).split())
```

Output

```
['5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Comment: Is there no way of doing it without it? I'm unfortunately limited in implementation and could only provide the RegEx to be used with the `re` module.

Comment: @daedsidog I have added a version with a capture group and split.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I cannot use it :(

Comment: @daedsidog What are the possible values for `B:` ? only a single digit? What is the maximum number of occurrences?

Comment: This is my simplification for much stranger patterns, but I'm afraid the digits can vary in length and their occurances are also varied.